# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function:67

Tags: jquery

**index.js**

```
var processResult = function (items) {

    return items;
};

function queryDB(callback) {

    var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM DEMO";
    db.transaction(

    function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],

        function (tx, results) {
            var item_Codes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                item_Codes.push({
                    item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode
                });
            }
            callback(item_Codes);
        }), errorCB;
    });
    return false;
}
```

Save.js

```
queryDB(processResult, function (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (i, elem) {

    });
});
```

I used above code to retrieve data from internal storage and populate inside a array ir run well.But gives the following error
11-14 11:34:03.929: E/Web Console(8538): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function:67

Comment: what line is line 67? what's the code there that causing the error?

Comment: callback(item_Codes);

Comment: see my answer, you're overloading too many arguments on `queryDB` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST ERROR:**

it seems like `queryDB` accepts only 1 argument (callback), but you're passing **2**.

try passing only the callback, by replacing in **save.js**:

```
queryDB(processResult, function(arr) {
```

replace with:

```
queryDB(function(arr) {
```

your exception is caused because the passed argument `processResult` is trying to fire as a function (acts as 'callback' parameter, which i guess you didn't want).

**SECOND ERROR:**

replace:

```
item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode
```

with:

```
item_code: results.rows.item[i].itemCode
```

javascript array items are referenced with `[]` and not `()`.

hope that helps.